# Server Hosting Error in C#

Tags: c#

I developed a eCommerce Website using ASP.Net 3.5 and C#. It is working good with Visual Stdio 2010. I uploaded my website to my domain under the public folder.
It show the error like below: [image: Local and server-side errors]

Click for full-size, or here's the stack trace fragment from the local error page.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   SageFrame.Framework.PageBase.OptimizeJs(List`1 lstJsColl, Int32 Mode) +7940
>   SageFrame.Framework.PageBase.LoadModuleJs() +944
>   SageFrame.Framework.PageBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +233
>   System.Web.UI.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +107

It was working fine before!

The code of the page_Load() is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedCurrency = string.Empty;
        string MainCurrency = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            StoreSettingConfig ssc = new StoreSettingConfig();
            MainCurrency = ssc.GetStoreSettingsByKey(StoreSetting.MainCurrency, GetStoreID, GetPortalID, GetCurrentCultureName);
            if (Session["SelectedCurrency"] != null && Session["SelectedCurrency"] != "")
            {
                selectedCurrency = Session["SelectedCurrency"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedCurrency = MainCurrency;
            } 

            string islive = Request.Form["custom"];
            string test = string.Empty;
            const string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            const string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            test = bool.Parse(islive.Split('#')[6]) ? strSandbox : strLive;

            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(test);
            //Set values for the request back
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
            string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
            strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
            req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
            var streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            var streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();            
            if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {
                string payerEmail = Request.Form["payer_email"];
                string paymentStatus = Request.Form["payment_status"];
                string receiverEmail = Request.Form["receiver_email"];
                string amount = Request.Form["mc_gross"];
                string invoice = Request.Form["invoice"];
                string addressName = Request.Form["address_name"];
                string addressStreet = Request.Form["address_street"];
                string addressCity = Request.Form["address_city"];
                string addressZip = Request.Form["address_zip"];
                string addressCountry = Request.Form["address_country"];
                string transID = Request.Form["txn_id"];
                string custom = Request.Form["custom"];

                string[] ids = custom.Split('#');
                int orderID = int.Parse(ids[0]);
                int storeID = int.Parse(ids[1]);
                int portalID = int.Parse(ids[2]);
                string userName = ids[3];
                int customerID = int.Parse(ids[4]);
                string sessionCode = ids[5];
                string pgid = ids[7];

                var tinfo = new TransactionLogInfo();
                var tlog = new TransactionLog();

                tinfo.TransactionID = transID;
                tinfo.AuthCode = "";
                tinfo.TotalAmount = decimal.Parse(amount);
                tinfo.ResponseCode = "1";
                tinfo.ResponseReasonText = "";
                tinfo.OrderID = orderID;
                tinfo.StoreID = storeID;
                tinfo.PortalID = portalID;
                tinfo.AddedBy = userName;
                tinfo.CustomerID = customerID;
                tinfo.SessionCode = sessionCode;
                tinfo.PaymentGatewayID = int.Parse(pgid);
                tinfo.PaymentStatus = paymentStatus;
                tinfo.PayerEmail = payerEmail;
                tinfo.CreditCard = "";
                tinfo.RecieverEmail = receiverEmail;
                tinfo.CurrencyCode = selectedCurrency;
                tlog.SaveTransactionLog(tinfo);


                if (paymentStatus.Equals("Completed"))
                {                    
                    var paypalobj = new PayPalHandler();
                    paypalobj.ParseIPN(orderID, transID, paymentStatus, storeID, portalID, userName, customerID, sessionCode);
                }


            }
            else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
            {
                //log for manual investigation
            }
            else
            {
                //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
            }
            // }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProcessException(ex);
          //  throw new Exception("This Page is not accessible!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your IIS server is running the correct version of the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it appears that your store library cannot be loaded.  This could be because it isn't installed on the server or the trust level is too low.

Either way, your hosting provider could assist with the setup.